# Prove that stochastic process trajectories are continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider gaussian process $\{X_{t}, t \in [0,1]\}$ with zero mean and covariance function $R(X_{s}, X_{t}) = \min (s,t) -st$.

We want to know does this process has continous trajectories, i.e. $\lim_{t \to t_0} X_t = X_{t_0}$ a.e.

My attempt :

First of all let's prove that this process contiunous in $L_{2}$. Consider $\mathbb{E}(X_{t+h} - X_{t})^{2} = h \to 0$ (the same result may be proved by proving continuity of covariance function).

Next we have that it's continuous in measure (because of convergence in average). But we know that probability of $\mathbb{P}(\{ \lim X_t \to X_{t_0} \})$ is continuous function, so we may use Riesz theorem which give us subsequence converging almost sure. Am I right? Hard problem for me actually. I don't know how it can be proven only by definitions.

Comment: Doesn't Chebyshev's/Markov inequality work?

Comment: @StanTendijck how it can be usefull?

Comment: I was thinking, $P(|X_h-X_0|>\epsilon)\leq E[X_h-X_0|^2]/\epsilon=h/\epsilon\to0$ since you have proved the continuity in $L^2$, right? (Not 100 percent sure about this reasoning though)

Comment: You have to be careful about exceptional null sets. Say, $t_n \to t_0$, then you get a subsequence $t_{n(k)}$ of $t_n$ such that $X(t_{n(k)} \to X_{t_0}$ almost surely... however the exceptional null set where convergence fails to hold depends on $(t_n)_n$... and that's a problem because the union over these exceptional sets will, in general, blow up.

Comment: @StanTendijck thats give us continuity in measure, not almosg sure.

Comment: @saz so that's I'm talking about. Actually I think that there should be a contradictukn, but I cant find it.

Comment: As you can see from the answer below, the best what you can expect is that $X$ has a modification with continuous sample paths (...because modifying the process on a null set destroys continuity but keeps all the distributional properties).

Comment: @saz as I can see the answer doesnt keep covariance. So the best way to consider Kolmogorov's theorem of continous modification?

Comment: @openspace my answer keeps the covariance as explained. Please reconsider your vote down.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that such a process $X_t$ exists and is continuous (i.e. $X_t$ is a Brownian bridge).

Take $U$ an independent uniform variable over $[0,1]$ and let $Y_t=X_t+1_{U.t \in \mathbb Q}$.

Then for all $t$, $\mathbb P(X_t=Y_t)=\mathbb P(U.t \not \in \mathbb Q)=1$ so $Y_t$ is a gaussian process with the same mean and covariance as $X_t$, however almost surely it is continuous nowhere.

This shows in general that mean and variance of a stochastic process never guarantee its continuity.

Comment: Then covariance funcrion may be different and all gaussian processes on segment have discountinius trajectories?

Comment: I mean we know that Wiener process has continious modification, but thats not garantee that the former process has it.

Comment: So why trajectories of our process will be discontinous?

Comment: They might be continuous (take the Brownian bridge for instance), or they might not (see my counterexample).

Comment: actually why covariance is the same ?

Comment: and why Brownian bridge has continous trajectories

Comment: I guess the covariance isnt the same almost everywhere

Comment: Doesn't BB have continuous trajectories per definition, i.e., one assumption on a Brownian Motion is that it is almost surely continuous.

Comment: Yes Brownian bridge/motion have continuous trajectories by definition.

Comment: @openspace, covariance function is the same because for any given $t$, $X_t=Y_t$ almost surely.

Comment: Am I right : $cov(Y_t , Y_s) = cov(X_t +1, X_s+1 ) = cov(X_t,X_s) + 1$ ?

Comment: No. $1_{U.t\in \mathbb Q}$ is a process which equals $1$ if $U.t$ is rational, $0$ otherwise. Its paths are never continuous anywhere. However, for a given $t$, it is equal to $0$ almost surely (because the uniform law has no atoms and $\mathbb Q$ is countable). This is why $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are modifications of each other.